# Ubuntu 23.04 - booting to initramfs with UUID not detected

Tags: boot, initramfs, nvme, 23.04

I just upgraded my test box with latest ubuntu 23.04 which ships with kernel 6.2. This is very convenient for me due to modern hardware support.

Unfortunately, normal boot ends in initramfs mode and UUID not found and thus can't boot root. It boots very nice with the 6.2 recovery mode with basically no apparent errors anywhere - full boot is possible.

I'm using nvme for system and root partition. I have tried rootdelay option, too.

I checked root partition UUIDs in /etc/fstab and in grub config - they are identical everywhere. I tried to regenerate initramfs from recovery, updated grub, eye-checked the UUIDs - no avail. Changed UUIDs to /dev - no change. Normal boot mode dies miserably. What stops me from further debugging is that in the initramfs shell I can't use keyborad like no usb hid modules present. So I can't check what is passed to the initramfs.

Any ideas and suggestions how to debug this further?

Comment: When normal boot fails and boot in recovery mode succeeds, the problem is often that the Linux built in graphics drivers cannot manage the graphics chip/card. In this case - **Please tell us about the graphics hardware (brand name and model)**. It might be possible to install a proprietary graphics driver and release the full power of the graphics hardware.

Comment: it is not connected with graphics in any way, as it fails just before root mount. It is Intel UHD 770 built into i7-12600 cpu. The problem is that for some strange reason, UUID of root partition is not detected during normal boot, but just adding "recovery" keyword allows to boot it fully with all devices enabled properly.

Comment: OK. You wrote that it is a test box. Then I suggest that you download the current Ubuntu iso file, make a USB boot drive and try it live. If/when that seems to work well, you can try to install Ubuntu into your test computer, and report the result here. - The reason why I suggest a fresh installation is that upgrading from one version to the next version is much more likely to fail. In a non-test-box case, I would backup the personal files (documents, pictures, home-made scripts etc) and copy them into the new system after the fresh installation.

Comment: This was interesting as what you suggested helped me a little. Using the Grub) advanced options and recovery allowed me at least to get to a login screen. However when logging in I was just left with a 640x400 blank screen. I use a product called ilo 4 on a hp microserver gen 8 so I can remotely see the boot screen. I can ssh into my server, but rdp no longer works. The issue about the graphics hardware seems to be a way forward as I run my machine headless. It does have a graphics "card" on the mobo, not sure what it is. But this did work 22.10