# Stuck on boot after 22.10 -> 23.04 Upgrade

Tags: boot, drivers, 23.04

This problem seems to be similar to what's described in a [few](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464622/stuck-on-reboot-after-ubuntu-23-04-install) [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464663/ubuntu-23-04-booting-to-initramfs-with-uuid-not-detected) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464727/after-clean-install-of-23-04-ubuntu-wont-boot), in that the symptoms seem to be identical - after an upgrade to 23.04, I can't boot past the manufacturer splash screen.  What seems to be different is that this is on a laptop without a video card - there's no nvidia drivers.  The machine is a Thinkpad X1 Carbon only running Ubuntu (no dual-boot)

Prior to the final update, my computer was using the `i915` video driver.  After booting into recovery mode, no video driver was listed as in use - though I'm not sure if this is because I was in recovery mode.

Would appreciate any help figuring out what driver might be causing me problems!

Comment: FWIW, tried again after a few months and having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. Every time I upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 my workstation won't boot. All I get is a message about Kernel Panic.

I have tried several times with a clean 22.10 install I can't even boot into recovery mode so can't play with drivers.

Grateful for your advice